# Can compose parameterized Type object in scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a list of types

```
val types:List[Type] = List(typeOf[Int], typeOf[Float], typeOf[MyObject], ...)
```

is it possible to map this into a new collection who's elements are lists types parameterized by the above types?

```
types.map( ??? ) === List(typeOf[List[Int]], typeOf[List[Float]], typeOf[List[MyObject]], ...)
```

Comment: I have always thought type parameters are erased at runtime, so there is no difference between `List[Int]` and `List[Float]`.

Comment: The list in the first example contains the full type information. Type erasure is only relevant when asking for the type from an object. The runtime objects has no need for its parameters. However you can fully inspect a parameterized class if you ask the compiler for it by referencing the type directly. The same is true for Scala and Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val tpeList = typeOf[List[_]]
types.map(tpe => appliedType(tpeList, List(tpe)))
```